# Where is the location of Firebase Analytics and Performance logs found on mobile devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Similar to the `./Fabric` directory (on an Android device) that would contain event logs, is there an analogous directory when it comes to Firebase's Analytics? For example, if we call `firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", null)`, where would this be logged?

Answer (score 1):

There are no text-based logs that can be easily read.  The only records are stored in a database in the app's own private space (inaccessible over a normal adb connection), and those records are periodically flushed to the backend and deleted from the device.